# how to check if a specified key has a value or not in hashmap in java

Tags: java

How to get to know if a particular key in an hash map has a ***value*** or not,

If so how can i be able to set the particular value of a key to another key in an hash map . 
Thanks

Comment: `if (map.get(key) != null) {... do something ...}` But what is your specific question? The first part of your question appears to be trivial and the 2nd part of your question is confusing without code and pertinent background information. Please check out the [help] and the [ask] to see what information we need in your question.

Comment: `map.replace(key, map.get(otherKey));`

Answer (score 1):

Check if a key exist in map is

```
if(map.contains(key))
```

Set a existing value from a key to another

```
map.put(newkey, map.get(oldkey));
```